# I'm getting an error in "id" and "value" values ​while making a ToDo List application

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am making a ToDo List application using React. As far as I know, I tried to write my code without making any mistakes, but I am getting an error about the id and value values ​​from my code. I leave my code below so you can see it. What could be the reason for this and where am I going wrong?

**My Code:**

```
import React, {useState} from "react"

export default function HomeTemplate() {

  const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  function addItem() {

    if(!newItem) {
      alert("Enter a value!")
      return
    }

    const ıtem = {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),
      value: newItem
    }

    setItems(oldItems => [...oldItems, items])
    setNewItem("");
  }

  function deleteItem(id) {
    const newArray = items.filter(item => item.id !== id);
    setItems(newArray)
  }

  return (
    <div className="">
      
      <div>
        <h1>ToDo List</h1>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="" value={newItem} onChange={e => setNewItem(e.target.value)}></input>

        <button onClick={() => addItem()}>Add</button>
      </div>

      <div>
        <ul>
          {items.map(item => {
            return(
              <li key={item.id}>{item.value} <button onClick={() => deleteItem(item.id)}>X</button></li>
            )
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

**Errors I get:**
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, **error messages**, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: The errors are TypeScript errors, but there are no TypeScript type annotations in your code. Are you using TypeScript on purpose, or did you mean to use JavaScript?

Comment: (Fundamentally, the issue is that `useState([])` has no type information for what the elements of the array would be, so the result is of type `never[]` as you can see. You could fix it in TypeScript by providing a type argument: `useState<AppropriateTypeHere[]>([])`, if you're intentionally using TypeScript.)

Comment: You're right, I entered the tag incorrectly. I changed it now.

Comment: I wasn't talking about tags. Your code is pure JavaScript, no type annotations in sight, but the error is from TypeScript. Do you mean to be using TypeScript?

Comment: `useState<AppropriateTypeHere[]>([])` I got rid of errors using this. Like you said, I have to use it on purpose. Thank you.

Comment: Glad that helped! Just for the avoidance of doubt, when I said "on purpose" I literally just meant "did you really mean to use TypeScript," it wasn't a comment on how well you were using it. I wasn't at all sure you wanted to be using TypeScript until you changed the tags. :-)